# Is it possible to receive a result of a broadcast in the activity that launches the broadcast?

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcast

I'm developing an application in Android Studio. This application has a fragment, say A, that launches an activity, say B, when user clicks. The activity B launches a broadcast, there reads a received SMS and gets a code. This code has to be sent to the activity B, and the activity B has to write the code in an editText.

So, the application receives a code verification for login... how can I do it?

[Imagen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzBcX.png)

[Imagen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZd5O.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, but not with `sendBroadcast()`. Instead, you'll have to use `sendOrderedBroadcast()`.

However, this does require you to setup a receiving BroadcastReceiver, since by default, only BroadcastReceivers can listen to a Broadcast, so even if an Activity is allowed to send a Broadcast, it can't listen to one, even if it's feedback.

But if you don't want to use `sendOrderedBroadcast()`, there's nothing stopping you from having your BroadcastReceiver send a result Broadcast to a BroadcastReceiver that you've setup in your Activity.

Yes, both solutions sounds extremely similar, because the requirements to allow an Activity to be able to listen to a broadcast is the same.

Comment: Thank you! You answer helped me understand it and I resolved my problem!